# New open folders or files are not in focus (they are in the background) in Windows 7.Why?

Tags: windows-7

When I open a picture, my picture viewer (windows live photo gallery) opens in the background, behind the window with the pictures.When i open other files, like some movie, the movie viewer opens behind the open window and when I open other folders is the same...Recently I formatted my laptop and before the format everything was ok. Why is this happening? It's very annoying!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some looking around it seems that the problem stems from a program that you have installed, Object Dock was the culprit on two systems that have had this issue.  After disabling the software everything goes back to normal use.

If you do not have that software installed I would recommend reading through this [document](http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/msconfig_win7.html) to try to eliminate some of your unused startup applications.

Comment: thank you sooo much!!! :D I have Object Dock and when I disable it the problem is gone!!! :D Again thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome I'm glad I could help

Comment: Unbelievable. Have had this issue for a year now and thought it was Windows 7 behavior. Damn Object Dock, you are uninstalled!